# Is it possible to subscribe to an input's changes/value change using viewChild rather that ngModal or formGroup / formControlName

Tags: angular, rxjs

In my Angular Component template I have an input like so

```
<input #myInput>
```

Not much to see there, but what I would like to do is detect when the value of my input changes without using a `formGroup` or `[(ngModal)]`. I thought I could do something like this in my component, naturally I have simplified the code

```
export class MySillyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('myInput') myInput: any;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.myInput.changes.subscribe((e) => console.log(e));
  }
}
```

However this gives me the error `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined`. Okay, so perhaps there is no `changes` property. I thought about changing `changes`to `valueChanges` but `valueChanges` is used with ReactiveForms (I think). So my question is, how can I subscribe to changes on an input using Angular without using `ngModal` or a Form?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `formGroup` or `[(ngModel)]`? They make doing this kind of thing extremely simple

Comment: I am using a child component where to extend a formGroup from a parentForm would have technical problems (hard to explain) and I can't mix ngModal with formGroup

Comment: Just use `(input)` event or `fromEvent(this.myInput.nativeElement, 'input').subscribe`

Comment: `(keyup)="changes($event)" ` then in component `changes(e) {console.log(e.target.value);}`